# Is it possible to commit murder-suicide by hijacking a body for a short period of time?

Tags: internal-consistency

The world is similar to that from the novel and TV series *Altered Carbon,* where a person's entire conscious is stored in a chip at the base of their skull and they can be transferred to different bodies at will.

In my world, a devious hacker has figured out a way to temporarily hijack the motor functions of a person and take full control of their body from the neck down for a short period of time (~5 seconds).  Since the hacker  is merely controlling the body and not fully posessing it, assume the body will obey all commands with all mental and neural inhibitors removed, so the body will not flinch and stop its action when it feels pain, etc.

Is it possible for the hacker to commit murder by causing the person's body to inflict traumatic damage to themselves, such as breaking/twisting their own neck or ripping out their own heart?    Lets assume he can't count on having any handy items nearby (no knives, not near a train track or high cliff, etc).

Also, the victim will still have control of their head, that includes mouth, nose, eyes, etc.

Note, please disregard the conscious transferring aspect the chip brings, I'm merely interested in the termination of the physical body.

Comment: Please note that the neural control you're suggesting doesn't make sense.  The chip (for reasons unexplained) can take control of brain-outgoing signals (control of the muscles) but not brain-incoming signals (feedback, necessary for everything including pain).  I call that a "technology dichotomy" and it's a serious weakness in the idea.  I've not read the book nor watched the series, but it would be funny if the chip were anything other than a ghost drive: data in, but no control or data out.  Are you changing this?  Why would someone want a chip that could control the body?

Comment: @JBH I did say it was similar, not exactly the same.  I thought expanding on it would take too long and wouldn't contribute to the question which is whether or not its possible for a hijacked body to do enough traumatic damage to itself with no outside tools in a short period of time.

Comment: A more valueable way to ask this question might be, "given a person whose arms are strong enough to break another person's kneck, what are the inhibitors that would stop such a person from breaking his own neck?"  Once you have that list of inhibitors, it's just storybuilding to work around them.

Comment: @JBH thanks, I think I got enough of an idea from the current answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

Contracting significant muscle tissue would produce symptoms similar to malignant hyperthermia.
Malignant hyperthermia is a disorder where:

"[...]the medications induce the release of stored calcium ions within muscle cells.[1] The resulting increase in calcium concentrations within the cells cause the muscle fibers to contract.[1] This generates excessive heat and results in metabolic acidosis.[1]"

The effects of the hijacker maximizing muscle contractions in the host would be "a very high temperature, an increased heart rate and abnormally rapid breathing, increased carbon dioxide production, increased oxygen consumption, mixed acidosis, rigid muscles, and rhabdomyolysis.[5]"

Its basically like heatstroke and it is lethal.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malignant_hyperthermia

There are probably other ways to use musculature alone as a weapon, such as restricting bloodflow, or stopping respiration.

But we don't even need to get that esoteric because such a highjacker would, definitely, be able to kill the host without tools. All they have to do is repeatedly slam the host's head against any hard surface.

Barring that, they have control of the hands, which can be used to beat the host to death, or inflict other trauma. One word: eyes.

Comment: Malignant hyperthermia is an interesting idea (thank you for the link) but it does not appear that it would be fatal within the 5 seconds of control that the OP specified.

Comment: The OP didn't specify that when I wrote the answer ;-)

Comment: I like this idea, how long of a time do you think would be needed to kill someone this way?

Comment: @z unfortunately i havent found a good answer to that. This sort of thing usually happens under controlled conditions and is treated immediately. A better indicator would be how long it takes someone to die of heatstroke, which i haven't found stats for.

Answer (score 5):

For 'trivial murder', I'd say it's dubious if you cannot guarantee the body has the enhanced physiology necessary for the limbs/neck to do damage to the important parts of the body. IMO your best bet would be freezing all vital organ function for the whole duration the body is controlled, but depending on the length of time this might not be enough to guarantee bodily death.

However, the point of a setting like that is that the constraints of a body, including its destruction can now be worked around. 'True murder', meaning destruction of the chip that houses the consciousness would be effectively impossible without access to specific tools or engineered circumstances(eg: standing next to a vat of acid)

Comment: You're answer points out a significant issue, that of "true murder" and the pesky persistance of the chip.  +1.

Comment: And even if one chip is destroyed, what is the guarantee that there aren't backups somewhere outside the body? This would be a really cheap way to generate skilled work force: you only need to educate one person and then make a lot of copies of them, which means big companies and governments would be likely using this technique, especially if they don't believe in a "soul" which is unique to a person.

Comment: So an average body does not have the physiology to self terminate, so to speak?  Even with inhibitions removed?

Comment: @z- The whole ripping organs out with your hands business is a lot harder than films/TV tend to make it look. You can certainly do damage, but death is not assured. Also keep in mind your constraints of 1)really short window of opportunity and 2)no guaranteed access to helpful tools/circumstances. If you have a longer window you could ensure a fatality rate high enough to make "body hacking" a plausible attack vector, but 5 seconds tops makes it really hard.

Answer (score 4):

No.

And I quote
"a person's entire conscious is stored in a chip at the base of their skull and they can be transferred to different bodies at will."

Clearly you can't kill someone from physical damage unless you can destroy the chip. At best they'll have to uploaded into a new body but it's still not murder or suicide. At best it's sleeve damage as it's called in Altered Carbon.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean just killing the sleeve, the easiest way would be diving into the floor head first with the neck in a forced angle, crushing your windpipe with a hit if the sleeve has strong hands (well, fingers) and hitting your temples against an acute corner like a hard table.

Alternatively, if keys still exist, you can thrust one through your eye into the brain. Maybe you won't cause fatal damage (some people have survived worse impalements like railways spikes), but the sleeve will be probably quite damaged. Or try to stab the heart or your windpipe (again). Stabbing the heart with a blunt short object requires a bit of planification (basically, going below the ribcage) which I think it would be difficult to do in five seconds.

Killgrave in the first season of Jessica Jones favoured "jump through the window" or "jump into traffic". They are probably the easiest ways.